# How to run a command on Ubuntu just before reboot or shutdown

Tags: shutdown, reboot

I want to execute a script when I click on Reboot or Shutdown, but just before anything, so all filesystems are still mounted, like if I entered the command on Terminal, when the operating system is still running.
OS is Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: It's possible (pre-execution stanza in the shutdown and reboot targets) but tricky for a couple reasons. First is that it might need to inhibit shutdown while it runs, second is that it won't run in case of a power loss or or dead battery or somebody holding down the power button. That's why much housecleaning (like clearing /tmp) occurs during boot instead of shutdown.

Comment: Yes, it is possible and Ubuntu does this for every `runlevel`. Check folders `/etc/rc*.d/` (where star represents a number). You are interested in `0 - poweroff` and `6 - reboot`. You can create there Your custom scripts.